Eigendecomposition of Toeplitz matrix based on Circulant/Skew-Circulant
I am working with Toeplitz matrix, I know that a Toeplitz Matrix $T$ can be decompose as a sum of a circulant and skew circulant matrix which can be diagonalized using the DFT matrix
$T=C+S = F\Lambda_C F^H + DF\Lambda_S F^HD^H$
where D is $D=\text{diag}(exp(j\frac{\pi}{N}n)) n=0,...,N-1$.
My question is if we can obtain efficiently the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the following matrix efficiently
$F^HTF=\Lambda_C + F^HDF\Lambda_SF^HD^HF$
